# Why read table with binary search returns the first entry in case of duplicate entries in SAP ABAP?

Tags: algorithm, abap, binary-search

Binary search works with sorted entries. According to the algorithm if number of entries (n) are even , then it first search the n/2th  entry . If it is the key , then it is returned otherwise it checks if the key is less than or greater than the n/2 the position. If it is less , then the search continues from index 1 to n/2 -1, discarding the rest half. Similarly the process repeats until the searched key is found.
In case of odd number of entries, the middle position is n-1/2.

So my question is if there are duplicate entries and we have sorted it in ascending order like 11122233. Now if we do read table binary search with key = 1(please ignore the syntax), then according to the algorithm,  n/2 = 4. But 4th position is not 1, so search continues from 1 to 4th  position. Now, n/2 = 2nd position which is 1 and it is the key. So the search stops at 2nd index. So second index is returned.

But in abap with read table binary search the first entry of 1, that is index 1 is returned. Why so? Please explain.

Comment: There are variants of binary search. Some do not stop when they find the key, but continue to make sure they find the first occurrence. [See here](http://www.ffbit.com/blog/2013/02/26/first-occurrence-binary-search/). There is not much to say about this. SAP is free to implement whatever they feel is most useful, no?

Comment: Agree with the previous participant. SAP is free to implement any variant of algorithm they want. It's sort of questions "why the sky is blue?"

Comment: That means SAP uses this sort of variant of binary search.But it's definitely not a question like why sky is blue.

Comment: Imho, this way it is much more reliable and therefore less error-prone...

Comment: futu is correct.  They do this so that they can guarantee all read table statements return the first entry.  that way you dont have to worry about the logic changing because of the "using binary search" clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the algorithm [has been specified and implemented that way](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapread_table_free.htm#!ABAP_ONE_ADD@1@):

> When the addition BINARY SEARCH is used, if there are multiple hits
>   (due to an incomplete search key or duplicate entries in the table),
>   the first hit according to the order of the rows in the primary index
>   is returned. This is the row with the lowest row number.

The rationale behind that would be that you would prefer a language to exhibit a stable behavior - adding some totally unrelated entries to the end of the table should not change what the `READ TABLE` statement locates.